# Add a description to CompletableFuture orTimeout

Tags: java, completable-future

What is the easy way to add some addition info into the timeout exception? Suppose I have a code like that:

```
CompletableFuture<ResutType> getSomething()
{
  ... return someFuture.orTimeout(15, SECONDS);
}
```

This is all I'm getting currently downstream later on when callers of the method trying to do `get()`:

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.reportGet(CompletableFuture.java:396)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(CompletableFuture.java:2073)
```

I need to add more info - which operation has timed out, how long timeout was, etc.. In other words I need some message to the exception like "The Something timed-out in 15s", ideally use a supplier like:

```
CompletableFuture<ResutType> getSomething()
{
   return someFuture.orTimeout(15, SECONDS, () -> new TimeoutException("The Something timed-out in 15s"));
}
```

Comment: You may throw new exception in `exceptionally()` with your message

Comment: There isn't quite enough information to say. Do you know that information about your future when you call `someFuture.orTimeout`?

Comment: @matt updated the question with an example I would like to have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`exceptionallyCompose`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CompletionStage.html#exceptionallyCompose(java.util.function.Function)) (or any of the async variants of this method) for that:

```java
public final class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
        CompletableFuture<String> future = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
                    sleep(3000);
                    return "DONE";
                })
                .orTimeout(1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .exceptionallyCompose(throwable -> {
                    if (throwable instanceof TimeoutException) {
                        var tex = new TimeoutException("The Something timed-out in 15s");
                        return CompletableFuture.failedFuture(tex);
                    }
                    return CompletableFuture.failedFuture(throwable);
                });

        sleep(2000);
        future.get();
        sleep(5000);
    }

    private static void sleep(long ms) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(ms);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

If your code fails due to a `TimeoutException`, you can return a `TimeoutException` (or any other throwable) that has more detail via a failed `CompletableFuture`. Otherwise, you can just return the same throwable that caused one of the previous stages to be completed exceptionally.

For example, if there had been some `RuntimeException` in `supplyAsync`, `future.get()` would still cause a `RuntimeException` (wrapped within an `ExecutionException`) to be thrown. If there is no exception (i.e. also no timeout), you `get()` your result normally.

With that knowledge you can write your own little `orTimeout` wrapper, for example:

```java
public static <T> CompletableFuture<T> orTimeout(
        CompletableFuture<T> cf,
        long timeout, TimeUnit unit
) {
    return cf.orTimeout(timeout, unit).exceptionallyCompose(throwable -> {
        if (throwable instanceof TimeoutException) {
            final var msg = String.format(
                    "The Something timed-out in %d %s.",
                    timeout, unit
            );
            return CompletableFuture.failedFuture(new TimeoutException(msg));
        }
        return CompletableFuture.failedFuture(throwable);
    });
}
```

and then use it for all `CompletableFuture`s like so:

```java
CompletableFuture<String> future = orTimeout(CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
    sleep(10000);
    return "DONE";
}), 1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

Comment: This is better. I've missed the `exceptionallyCompose` magic. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the same facility as the `CompletableFuture`’s internal timeout handling:

```java
public static <T> CompletableFuture<T> customTimeOut(
    CompletableFuture<T> cf, long time, TimeUnit unit,
    Supplier<? extends Exception> s) {

    CompletableFuture.delayedExecutor(time, unit, cf.defaultExecutor())
        .execute(() -> { if(!cf.isDone()) cf.completeExceptionally(s.get()); });

  return cf;
}
```

Note that the `isDone()` check is not strictly necessary, as `completeExceptionally` does nothing if the future is already completed. The check is only there to prevent the potential expensive exception construction when not necessary. It’s still possible, but rather unlikely that the future gets completed right between the `isDone()` and the `completeExceptionally` call, but nothing bad will happen then, as said, because `completeExceptionally` does the right thing anyway.

You can test it like

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for(int timeOut = 1; timeOut < 5; timeOut += 2) {
        System.out.println("time-out " + timeOut + " sec");
  
        CompletableFuture<String> cf = customTimeOut(
            CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
                LockSupport.parkNanos(2_000_000_000);
                return "result";
            }),
            timeOut, TimeUnit.SECONDS,
            () -> new TimeoutException("timeout with my custom message")
        );
    
        try {
            System.out.println("ordinary result: " + cf.join());
        }
        catch(Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace(System.out);
        }
    }
}
```

```
time-out 1 sec
java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: timeout with my custom message
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.reportJoin(CompletableFuture.java:413)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.join(CompletableFuture.java:2118)
    at CF.main(CF.java:32)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: timeout with my custom message
    at CF.lambda$2(CF.java:28)
    at CF.lambda$0(CF.java:13)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$RunnableExecuteAction.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1395)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:373)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.topLevelExec(ForkJoinPool.java:1182)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:1655)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1622)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:165)
time-out 3 sec
ordinary result: result
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hVPBbtswDL37K7icbDQxsgK7zGmHoe1OW3tIexqGQVWYVIksGRLVxijy7RkVO07TJB0ByxD1SD49UnPxLAbzyWK9VmVlHcGcHXkgpXNpjQzOoaH8ypaVRhKPGn8ECg6L5CP4vSrxwSj6P8oGullKrEhZ8zFaW7nw@U9ex6GKsCPwaTAyZsojRCt0RZJU4VErCVIL7@GXUCZ5TYCt9XsSxL/R/SUcXDI6ZfBky0j1LlC6iYx2HDvtg7ZmBsTwPmxVgMBLH7acRt8Al4Rm4qG7@iX4DCKv0wXyCWpR4@RmiTKQdWlTpMktp3w8FUFTd5xlXa5oOW4OME0zGFzCK6hp@onDlL@2Bhkdc8imKHa8hNZ16vMZEiMKWGXFjqNDpmU4rNg4VskRWZ@tmkDJoqdjcsrMfv8B4WbtXRubMldlaKMZSwwX8LnoNiP4stucXcD528ho49oTljmPUV5xAdIm7UX8gD3Qg7NdMO88yl5WtPF7aQ7b2fCNPWVGJ4bgdK987HX93ddGbgU/iIr2ZpzzSrjFrTDWp@d/h8Ph9usI71urfs@h5673DkGrrH/ga8XYjWY@vrm6u70eH0Ib1gZf4P0zbQSO@r4oeoKybuWBEr0XM@ztD94b/nt@cvURUY7107qJMoLhzV2/bvrK0zq3PFfZO31WezspSD6lHXV@eNmRorhsio1JyMW9ExLTHY@T@Vft2K@S9fof)

Comment: Interesting approach, thanks! I did some digging into the implementation of `orTimeout` and found out that it uses a seperate thread to call `completeExceptionally` while `cf.defaultExecutor()` (usually) returns `ForkJoinPool.commonPool()`. That might potentially be a problem if all threads in the common pool are already in use.

Comment: @AlexR Yes, looks not quite universal approach. And if the `someFuture` was created in a single-threaded executor, the timeout would just not work silently - happy debugging.

Comment: @AlexR the idea was that if someone really overrides `defaultExecutor()`, there must be a reason for it, so I wanted to support it. But yes, if that executor has no spare thread this would backfire. But the built-in implementation is even more fragile. It uses a dedicated single threaded executor for enforcing the timeout but the `CompletableFuture` doesn’t care whether the caller is that `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor`’s thread and may use it to process dependent stages, so you *have* exactly one thread that could easily be unavailable.

Comment: [Simple demonstration](https://tio.run/##tVKxTsMwEN3zFadMjqCWaAUDgUqowAKUIWVCDK7rtk4dO7LPFRHqtwe3CVVFIWJhsXV3753fu3PO1qyXz1Z1LYvSWIQ8JKhHqSg3mntrhUY6MkWpBLKpEvcevRVp1AWfyEK8aIndKGX4ytHHcGa@3MLSKCr9VEkOXDHn4IlJDR8RQJt1yDBcayNnUIQaydBKvXh9A2YXLtlBAY60XjWwIfD5GVwf16kLz6vqxlWaE5JAb9h2AjgQR0tmV2OmjSNf9mh2N3oe32YUTVM4T5K0ZVoRWmuI4yaxaQtd4vpBXJBIxTsXJUqjmVIVwUM9WeVQFNT4ICfQUGkyWVrBZrQdahMFEycQX0IcLtxL@oEcPwhRhucBl9KFY0uGqXdVvGfNjSVpmhyNgiR/dzbYOev/m7Nfhr0dprHbbYW2ZHAK3xe3x/UPcBcduAHNTfh3u3gTbaK6/gQ)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are expecting a timeout, consider making it part of the return type instead of dealing with the `TimeoutException`. One way is to change the result type to `Either<Timeout, Result>` using the [`Either`](https://docs.vavr.io/#_either) type of the [Vavr library](https://www.vavr.io/).

```
var future = CompletableFuture.<Either<Timeout, Result>>supplyAsync(() ->
    Either.right(lengthyCalculation()))
.completeOnTimeout(
    Either.left(new Timeout("Lengthy Calculation timed out", 12)), 1, SECONDS);
```

Once the future completed and you got hold of its value, use one of the many methods of `Either` to proceed. In the simplest case

```
Result result = future.get()
    .getOrElseThrow(timeout -> new RuntimeException(...));
```

Comment: This is just pleonasm, as the whole vavr thing. The `CompletableFuture` is already represents the same thing as `Either`, it could give either result or exception. And now it is just extra layer complexity.

Comment: @kan, if you look at it this way, then use `CompletableFuture.exceptionally` and `CompletableFuture.exceptionallyCompose`, which correspond to the left projection on `Either`.

Answer (score 0):

Naively I would say.

```
CompletableFuture future = CompletableFuture.runAsync( () ->{
    try{
        someFuture.get(15, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    } catch(Exception e){
        throw new RuntimeException("detailed message", e);
    }
});
```

Of course you should be a bit more specific about the exceptions, but I think this is the gist of the issue.